# How to limit joomla 1.5 main menu into 2 levels?

Tags: joomla

i have this menu structure: Products->Shoes->Men. i have this kind of menu structure because i have a specific module to be shown in the Men section only. my problem is how can i limit the rendering of my main menu only up to Shoes(that is up to Products->Shoes only). i hope i get the right question for you guys. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In the admin area go to Modules

Find your Menu and in the parameters you have the option to change how many levels get rendered